# PHP for : IF URL = string else

Tags: php, url

I've made progress here , updating this support request .. i cannot add code to this it won't save - this is very difficult , spent 5 minutes sending this simple message.

ltrim removes prefix "/"  AND ..
preg-replace remove suffix "?page=*"

so that :
URL = /city = city
URL = /city?page=* = city

Comment: Echo or print the `$host` variable to see what the value contains, then that should help see how that looks. I'm thinking a slash may be missing. One thing with the comparison, use double quotes instead of single, and change the `<?=$profession[filename]?>` portion to `{$profession['filename']}`, since that part is already within PHP context. Also, though it might not error, short tags for the last `}` should have `<?php } ?>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `<?=...?>` inside a string, that can only be used when you want to print something from a context that's printing literal text.

Either use variable interpolation in a double-quoted string:

```
if($host == "https://www.purelocal.com.au/{$profession[filename]}")
```

or concatenation:

```
if($host == 'https://www.purelocal.com.au/' . $profession[filename])
```

Comment: If the variable is: <?=$profession[filename]?> , eg : category-name
If URL = category-name
THEN blank
ELSE
SOMETHING

how can i put this variable inside a PHP if URL string statement ?

Comment: something like this ?

<?php 
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == '{$profession['filename']}')
{ ?> 
1
<?php } else{ ?> 

2
<? } ?>

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, only double quotes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php